# Flow Templates and Managed Package Dependency

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package, workflow

If I mark a flow in a managed package as a template, when that flow gets copied and saved as a new flow, will it loose all dependency/relationship to the managed package.

For example, I have a Closed Opportunity flow that gets deployed from a managed package. Is it marked as a template as I want the customer to make edits to it based on their process.

When they go to make edits and save the flow as a new version, will that flow no longer be tied to the managed package it came from? When it comes to uninstalling the package, will the clone flow be part of the managed package dependency?

Answer (score 0):

> When they go to make edits and save the flow as a new version, will that flow no longer be tied to the managed package it came from?

That customer-created flow is not part of your managed package and is not part of your package's namespace.

> When it comes to uninstalling the package, will the clone flow be part of the managed package dependency?

It depends on what the flow does. If the flow references components that are part of your managed package, then yes, it would be identified as a dependency if the user attempts to uninstall the package.